# Google Analytics - user based segments

Tags: google-analytics

I have a user based segment created in GA that is working as expected. However, with user based segments, one can only apply a maximum date range of 90 days to the report. 
This is as per their documentation (Limits on segments): https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951?hl=en

1. Is there a workaround this? I have a use case where I would want to apply the user based segment over a date range of ~1-2 years to get a better sense on the trend over time.
2. If I re-create the GA report in Google Data Studio - is there a way to apply this user based segment over a longer date range?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there's no option for extending 90-days reporting timeframe. The only solution is to get user-level data through the Reporting API and process them within 3rd party software. However, to do that you'll need some custom tracking implemented beforehand.